# What are the chances for King Dedede's side+b to perform each of its variants?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

When using King Dedede's side+b attack, he can launch a variety of different objects:

- A round waddling guy who is rather useless
- A round waddling guy who shoots lightning occasionally
- A spikey black thing that deals good damage and has good knockback
- An item capsule

Are there any other options I missed?  What is the probability of each of these occurring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a **71.4% chance** of him throwing a [**Waddle Dee**](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Waddle_Dee), a **20.4% chance** of throwing a [**Waddle Doo**](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Waddle_Doo), and a **8.2% chance** of him throwing a [**Gordo**](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Gordo). The chance of an item being thrown appears to be "the same or slightly less than the chance of throwing a Gordo". (I guess what this means is the game makes the item calculation, and if the result is no, it does the monster calculation.) [[Source](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Waddle_Dee_Toss)]